# Richfaces: TargetList size limitation

Tags: richfaces, picklist

In `richface`, is there a way to limit the size of Target list to a certain limit? For example allowing maximum 5 entries and then Add button turns to false mode?

Answer (score 0):

Neither RichFaces 3 nor 4 has such a build-in functionality. So in this way: no. But generally you can do some things:

1. Add validation.
2. Add some JavaScript. Target list has class `rf-pick-tgt` and options have class `rf-pick-opt`. So it's easy to write a selector, count selected items and disable add button `<button class="rf-pick-add rf-pick-btn>`.
3. Override `rich:pickList` and add e.g. `maxEntries` attribute (probably this includes also points 1. and 2.).